# How can I map the headers to columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like :

```
A    B    C 
1    0    0
1    1    0
0    1    0
0    0    1
```

I want to have :

```
 A    B    C  label
 1    0    0   A
 1    1    0   AB
 0    1    0   B
 0    0    1   C
```

I've tried to do by map or apply but I couldn't figured it out.

Answer (score 21):

Here is an idiomatic and performant solution

```
df['label'] = np.where(df, df.columns, '').sum(axis=1)

   A  B  C label
0  1  0  0     A
1  1  1  0    AB
2  0  1  0     B
3  0  0  1     C
```

Comment: this is very elegant!

Comment: Nice one !!~ :)

Comment: @TedPetrou Is there a Numpy method which allows me to get something like "A+B" or "A/B" instead of "AB"? Can I join strings using any Numpy method?

Answer (score 13):

Using `dot`

```
df.assign(label=df.dot(df.columns))

   A  B  C label
0  1  0  0     A
1  1  1  0    AB
2  0  1  0     B
3  0  0  1     C
```

---

Same thing using underlying numpy arrays

```
df.assign(label=df.values.dot(df.columns.values))

   A  B  C label
0  1  0  0     A
1  1  1  0    AB
2  0  1  0     B
3  0  0  1     C
```

Comment: This is also very smart !

Comment: `df.dot(df.columns)` is very nice.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could multiply integers and objects

Comment: @TedPetrou yeah!  Astute observation about `df.columns.values` being of `dtype` `object`.  The following fails `df.values.dot(df.columns.values.astype(str))` as does `np.where(df, df.columns, '').astype(str).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 6):

```
In [101]: df['label'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(df.columns[x.astype(bool)].tolist()), axis=1)

In [102]: df
Out[102]:
   A  B  C label
0  1  0  0     A
1  1  1  0    AB
2  0  1  0     B
3  0  0  1     C
```

PS i would definitely chose [@Ted's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46186015/5741205) as it's much nicer and much much much ... faster

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal, our Pandas community is growing up - really appreciate this! :-)

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal It's the IPython terminal prompt, not a notebook. If the number is 101, that means there were 100 unsuccessful attempts to get the right answer... LOL ( j/k ;-) )

Comment: Yeah @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I was having trouble thinking of the collective term for IPython terminal prompts.

Answer (score 6):

Or using `melt` and `groupby`

```
df1 = df.reset_index().melt('index')
df1 = df1[df1.value==1]
df['label'] = df1.groupby('index').variable.sum()
df

Out[976]: 
   A  B  C label
0  1  0  0     A
1  1  1  0    AB
2  0  1  0     B
3  0  0  1     C
```

Or

```
df['label'] = df.T.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.index[x==1]),axis=0)
df
Out[984]: 
   A  B  C label
0  1  0  0     A
1  1  1  0    AB
2  0  1  0     B
3  0  0  1     C
```

Comment: Works but is fairly slow. You typically want to avoid groupby if possible

Comment: @TedPetrou see my second one :)

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal will start notice the format of my code today :)

Comment: @sunny you can upvote those answers, and please accept Ted's answer

Comment: You guys are much kinder than me. I'll have to soften my soul.

Comment: @TedPetrou For me the reputation is much less important than learn a good solution !!!!, Your answer make my day , I am working on replace some of my working code to your solution:), Have a nice day !

Answer (score 5):

```
df = df.assign(label=[''.join([df.columns[n] for n, bool in enumerate(row) if bool]) 
                      for _, row in df.iterrows()])
>>> df
   A  B  C label
0  1  0  0     A
1  1  1  0    AB
2  0  1  0     B
3  0  0  1     C
```

**Timings**

```
# Set-up:
df_ = pd.concat([df] * 10000)

%%timeit
# Solution by @Wen 
df1 = df_.reset_index().melt('index')
df1 = df1[df1.value==1]
df['label'] = df1.groupby('index').variable.sum()
# 10 loops, best of 3: 47.6 ms per loop

%%timeit
# Solution by @MaxU
df_['label'] = df_.apply(lambda x: ''.join(df_.columns[x.astype(bool)].tolist()), axis=1)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 4.99 s per loop

%%timeit
# Solution by @TedPetrou
df_['label'] = np.where(df_, df_.columns, '').sum(axis=1)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 12.5 ms per loop

%%timeit
# Solution by @Alexander
df_['label'] = [''.join([df_.columns[n] for n, bool in enumerate(row) if bool]) for _, row in df_.iterrows()]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 3.75 s per loop

%%time
# Solution by @PiRSquared
df_['label'] = df_.dot(df_.columns)
# CPU times: user 18.1 ms, sys: 706 µs, total: 18.8 ms
# Wall time: 18.9 ms
```