# Elegant way to produce description of columns based on column data

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
index    data1    data2
1        30       20
2        20       10  
3        40       90
```

I want to produce an array of descriptions, one for each row, indicating whether piece of data was significant.

I define significant as having value over 25, so I want the following array:

```
['data1 was significant', '',  'data1 was significant\ndata2was significant']
```

I know that I can go through each row and check each column and build an array, but I am wondering if there is an elegant way to do this using pandas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`dot` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185965/how-can-i-map-the-headers-to-columns-in-pandas/46186369#46186369):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'data1': [30, 20, 40],
    'data2': [20, 10, 90]
}, index=[1,2,3])

df.gt(25).dot(df.columns + ' was significant\n').str.strip().tolist()
# ['data1 was significant', '', 'data1 was significant\ndata2 was significant']
```

Answer (score 3):

Or, use `np.where`.

```
[''.join(x) for x in np.where(df > 25, df.columns + ' was significant\n', '')] 
['data1 was significant\n',
 '',
 'data1 was significant\ndata2 was significant\n']
```

Comment: @piRSquared I'm usually frugal... today they're already gone and there's 9 hours left in the day.

Comment: I was up all night.  And well... you know /shrug

Answer (score 3):

Or, using `apply`

```
In [323]: (df.gt(25).apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(
                       ['%s was significant' % c for c, v in x.iteritems() if v]), axis=1)
             .tolist())
Out[323]: ['data1 was significant', '', 'data1 was significant\ndata2 was significant']
```