# Return pandas data frame with certain value "1"

Tags: python, pandas, search, dataframe, lambda

I am looking for the most simple and direct way to return a data frame or list of column names that have the value "1".

Say I start with this:

```
import pandas as pd 

dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=4, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'W01': [0, 0, 0, 1], 'W02': [0, 1, 0, 0], 'W03': [0, 0, 0, 1]
              },
             index = dates)

df

           W01  W02 W03
2017-01-01  0   0   0
2017-01-02  0   1   0
2017-01-03  0   0   0
2017-01-04  1   0   1
```

And I want a dataframe that ends up like this. Or another more intelligent way of grouping the columns with values of "1".

```
           Value  X1    X2  
2017-01-01  1     NaN   NaN     
2017-01-02  1     W02   NaN
2017-01-03  1     NaN   NaN
2017-01-04  1     W01   W03
```

Alternatively, the solution could return a list like this?

```
2017-01-01, NaN
2017-01-02, W02
2017-01-03, NaN
2017-01-04, W01, W03
```

My actual data frame has 85 columns and almost 700 rows. So the solution should be able to match these dimensions.

The `get_value` function from pandas seems okay, but I can't figure it out: `df.get_value(dates, col="1")`

Alternatively I could use lambda, but it does not provide all the information I'm looking for. 
`df.select(lambda x: x == '1', axis=1)`

Help?

Comment: Have you tried [`df.dot(df.columns + ", ").str.strip(", ")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242976/elegant-way-to-produce-description-of-columns-based-on-column-data/46243057#46243057)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

```
In [2784]: (df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.index[x.astype(bool)]), axis=1)
              .replace('', np.nan))
Out[2784]:
2017-01-01         NaN
2017-01-02         W02
2017-01-03         NaN
2017-01-04    W01, W03
Freq: D, dtype: object
```

Or,

```
In [2787]: df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.index[x.astype(bool)]), axis=1)
Out[2787]:
              0    1
2017-01-01  NaN  NaN
2017-01-02  W02  NaN
2017-01-03  NaN  NaN
2017-01-04  W01  W03
```

Answer (score 1):

setting up

```
df1=df.reset_index().melt('index')
df1=df1[df1.value.eq(1)]
```

1

```
df1.groupby('index')['variable'].apply(lambda x : ','.join(x)).to_frame().reindex(df.index)

Out[846]: 
           variable
2017-01-01      NaN
2017-01-02      W02
2017-01-03      NaN
2017-01-04  W01,W03
```

2

```
df1.groupby('index')['variable'].apply(lambda x : list(x)).apply(pd.Series).reindex(df.index)
Out[852]: 
              0    1
2017-01-01  NaN  NaN
2017-01-02  W02  NaN
2017-01-03  NaN  NaN
2017-01-04  W01  W03
```